# composeWithDevTools 'expected 1 argument, but got 2 error' while making store in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-saga, redux-devtools-extension

I was making store in React and I have an issue with Typescript saying that  **"composeWithDevTools expected 1 argument, but got 2".**
I searched around and I found many people wrote code like me so I couldn't find what the issue is
Is there anybody can explain why this error occurs and how I can fix this? I would really appreciate it!

```
import { applyMiddleware, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import reducer from './modules/reducer';
import createSagaMiddleware from '@redux-saga/core';
import rootSaga from './modules/rootSaga';

const create = () => {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const store = configureStore(
    reducer, 
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
    );

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

  return store;
}

export default create;
```

And the error message.

[image]

And this is my packages version.

```
"packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "my-books",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
        "@types/node": "^16.18.10",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.6.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.2.0",
        "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
        "redux-saga": "^1.2.2",
        "typescript": "^4.9.4",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
        "@types/redux-actions": "^2.6.2"
      }
```

Comment: I guess there should be `createStore` instead of `configureStore`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You are mixing syntaxes between redux's `createStore` and redux-toolkit's `configureStore`.**

[`createStore`](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore) accepts 1-3 arguments: `(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])`

[`configureStore`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore) accepts 1 argument, which is a configuration object.

Proper use of `configureStore` looks like this:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import reducer from './modules/reducer';
import createSagaMiddleware from '@redux-saga/core';
import rootSaga from './modules/rootSaga';

const create = () => {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(sagaMiddleware)
  });

  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

  return store;
}

export default create;
```

You don't need `composeWithDevTools` with `configureStore` because DevTools is included by default, and [can be customized](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#devtools).

You also don't need to call `applyMiddleware` as that is [handled internally](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#middleware).  Here we are taking [the defaults](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware) and adding `sagaMiddleware`.